# Get only last created document per id when using $in

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 10.000 readings (documents) in MongoDB and I have an array of deviceIds. I need to get in Mongoose the lastly created document for each device.

My approach:

```
    Reading.find({
        "deviceId": { "$in": deviceIds} 
    },
    function(err, readings) {
         callback(err,readings);
    }).sort({createdAt:-1}).limit(1);
```

This obviusly returns only one document. I need to get one per each deviceId in the deviceIds array.

EDIT 21/02/2018: Thanks to the help of @mickl I changed my code to:

```
Reading.aggregate([
    {   $match: { "deviceId": { "$in": finalDevices}  } },
    {
        $group: {
            deviceId: "$deviceId",
            maxCreatedAt: { $max: "$createdAt" }
        }
    }
],function(err, reading) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, reading)
    }
})
```

Now I am getting the following error: "The field 'deviceId' must be an accumulator object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework's `$match` to filter your collection to specified devices and then use `$group` with [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to get the dates.

```
Device.aggregate([
    { $match: { "deviceId": { "$in": deviceIds}  } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$deviceId",
            maxCreatedAt: { $max: "$createdAt" }
        }
    }
],function(err, readings) {
         callback(err,readings);
})
```

Comment: I am getting the following error and I cannot fix it: "The field 'deviceId' must be an accumulator object". Theres something wrong with "$deviceId" I guess, but I don't find the solution...

Comment: @Egidi, could you paste sample doc here ?

Comment: you mean the code? I updated the OP with current code.

Comment: @Egidi the problem is that you're using deviceId: "$deviceId", but in my example there's _id: "$deviceId" because _id is a special field which is a grouping key and that's the problem here.